# The respective functions of two occurrences of "as" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, comparison

In the sentence

> Travelers must explore ***as*** much of the world ***as*** they can before it completely changes,

I am confused by the two occurrences of "as". What are their respective functions in the sentence?

Answer (score 3):

To put it simply, the phrase "[as much as](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+much+as)" is an idiom which means "to the same degree as (something else)".

> **as much as**
>
> 1. this or almost this amount- *These drugs can lead to as much as a 30 percent increase in sleep interruption.*
> 2. to the same degree as- *People who live with this plant consider it a friend as much as a foe.*

Think of your example sentence as consisting of two parts:

> Travelers must explore as much of the world

and

> as they can (before it completely changes)

When you look at it separately, the first part of the sentence says *travelers should explore **as much of the world***. Now, combine this with the second part: ***as they can*** before it completely changes.

The *as much of the world* (bold in first part) is compared with the degree of *as they can*(bold in second part). Put together, the sentence implies that travelers should explore the world to the fullest/completely(ie: as much as they can) before it completely changes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The two *as*es are not independent but part of a single construction, *as X as Y*. This construction defines the quantity, degree or quality which is attributed to *X* to be equal to the quantity, degree or quality which is attributed to *Y*.

For instance, if I say

> John is ***as***  happy ***as*** Mary.

I am defining the degree of John’s happiness: I am telling you ***how happy*** John is. I assert that John’s happiness is equal to Mary’s happiness—he is happy in the same degree ***as*** Mary.

In your sentence there is an ellipsis: the expression *as much of the world as they can* omits the complement of *can*, which is the same as the complement of *must*; in full the sentence would read

> Travelers must explore as much of the world as they can **explore** before it completely changes.

The *as...as...* construction thus defines ***how much*** of the world travelers must explore. The sentence asserts that that amount is equal to the amount of the world travelers *can* explore.